# Eigenvector Order in R

Tags: r, eigen, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am trying to work out an issue regarding the order of eigenvectors returned by eigen in r.  Consider the following:

```
covmatrix <- matrix(data = c(13, 5, 2, 4), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
covmatrix
eigen <- eigen(covmatrix)
eigen
```

The output returns:

```
values
[1] 14  3

vectors
          [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 0.8944272 -0.1961161
[2,] 0.4472136  0.9805807
```

Per the documentation, the first column should represent the eigenvector associated with the largest eigenvalue.  However, mathematically, when I calculate the eigenvectors I end up with column 2 associated with the eigenvalue 14 as 0.9805807 is 5 times 0.1961161.  The math is detailed [here](https://matrixcalc.org/en/vectors.html#eigenvectors%28%7B%7B13,5%7D,%7B2,4%7D%7D%29).  I'm sure I am missing something simple but can't quite work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not working with the same matrix. To get consistent result with what you derive analytically, you need

```
covmatrix <- matrix(data = c(13, 5, 2, 4), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

eigen(covmatrix)
$values
[1] 14  3

$vectors
          [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 0.9805807 -0.4472136
[2,] 0.1961161  0.8944272
```

Comment: Thanks!  I can't believe I missed the byrow.  I knew it had to be something simple.